# Characteristic functions total in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, characteristic-functions

Prove that $\left\{\mathcal{X}(a,x):x \in [a,b]\right\}$ is total in $L^2([a, b]), dx)$
where $\mathcal{X}(c,d)$ is the characteristic function of $(c, d)$.

What is the definition of being total? This problem is from the book Barry Simon. And that definition does not appear.
Does it mean to be dense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Total" means that the linear span of your set (i.e., the set of all functions of the form $c_1 \mathcal{X}(a,x_1) + c_2 \mathcal{X}(a, x_2) + \dots + c_n \mathcal{X}(a, x_n)$) is dense in $L^2([a,b])$.

Equivalently, the only function which is orthogonal to every function in your set, is the zero function.  (Proving these are equivalent is a good exercise.)

Comment: Let $S=span(\left\{\mathcal{X}_{(a,c)}:x\in [a,b]\right\})$ now
$L^2([a,b])=S\oplus S^{\perp}$
Let $f\in L^2([a,b])$
If $f \in S$ we are done
If $f\in S^{\perp}$, then $<f,s>=0 forall s\in S$
In particular, $<f,\mathcal{X}_{(a,x)}>=0 forall x\in [a,b]$
$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\mathcal{X}_{(a,x)}dx=0$
$\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx=0$. for all $x\in [a,b]$
It implies $f(x)=0$? ($f$ is not neccesary  continuos...)

Comment: Yes, if $\int_a^x f(t)\,dt = 0$ for all $x$, it does imply that $f = 0$ (almost everywhere).  This follows from an appropriate version of the fundamental theorem of calculus, for instance.

Comment: Then, $f(x)=0 $ a.e. and this, implies $L^2[a,b]=S $ and therefore $S$ is total in $L^2[a,b]$?

Comment: Yes, assuming that in your definition of $S$, the symbol $span$ means the **closed** span.